# Compiling in 32 Bit gives an error

Tags: c, linux, gcc, ubuntu

I'm compiling a program to assembly code, specifically in 32 bit form, and when I compile without the -m32 flag like so...:

```
gcc -S examples.c
```

It compiles fine. However when I do this...

```
 gcc -S -m32 examples.c
```

I get an error on my include stdlib.h (formatting taken out because it wasn't showing up in the preview window) line like so:

```
In file included from /usr/include/stdlib.h:25:0,
             from examples.c:1:
/usr/include/features.h:324:26: fatal error: bits/predefs.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

What's going on here?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Ubuntu.

Comment: You probably do not have `ia32-libs` installed. Can you run `sudo apt-get install ia32-libs` ? BTW the `predefs.h` file comes from `libc6-dev`. Make sure that package is installed as well.

Comment: @Tuxdude - ia32-libs install a ton of stuff, it shouldn't be necessary for just C library things.

Comment: I installed ia32-libs, but it did not fix the problem.

Comment: @SwiftCore - try the answer I gave below, it should work.

Comment: @teppic - agreed that `ia32-libs` does not have the header file like I stated, but he needs that for running 32-bit programs on his 64-bit installation anyways. And no it does not install a ton of stuff, just the basic 32-bit runtimes required for most C and C++ programs.

Comment: @Tuxdude: not for anything that is compiled just with the C library. ia32-libs is really just convenient runtime support for precompiled 32bit apps that have generally common external library dependencies.

Comment: @SwiftCore - as already stated, the `predefs.h` comes from `libc6-dev` package. Install it using `sudo apt-get install libc6-dev`. And yes if you've not already installed the 32-bit toolchain, you would required the `g++-multilib` package as well.

Comment: @Tuxdude: libc6-dev is the 64bit library, installed along with gcc (he needs the 32bit version, lib6-dev32 or something). g++-multilib is just a really convenient package as it pulls in all the necessary C/C++ 32bit libraries and headers together.

Comment: @teppic `libc6-dev-i386` does not contain the missing header file, but may be if you try to install it, it might automatically install `libc6-dev`, not sure. And the same could be true for `g++-multilib` too, don't really have a ubuntu box to verify :D

Comment: @Tuxdude: I just had a look (on 13.04), libc6-dev-i386 creates a link at /usr/include/bits to the right place, which fixes the problem. The header file is there, just in the wrong place without this package.

Answer (score 8):

You're missing the 32bit C libraries and headers. These aren't installed in 64bit Ubuntu by default, but you can do it (together with C++) by running:

```
$ sudo apt-get install g++-multilib
```